# stringstream << operator consuming a lot of memory inside a loop

Tags: c++, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, stringstream, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have an update method that is like an infinite loop because is run every frame. Inside this method I get a float and I have to convert it to an string every frame to post the socore in the screen.

I'm using the << operator that allows me to copy the float to an stringstream and then, i use the str() function to get the string value of the stream.

In the header file I declared `scoreString`, `actualScore` and `scoreLabel`.

```
update(dt){
    actualScore += combo;
    scoreString.str("");
    scoreString << actualScore;
    scoreLabel->setString(scoreString.str());
    scoreString.clear();
}
```

`actualScore` is the float that I want to convert to a string. For that purpuse, I use the scoreString object that is an `stringstream`. To recycle this `stringstream` I use the `str("")` function that set the value to nothing, and so I don't have to create the object every time that the loop is run.

This code it's used inside a cocos2dx application, and it's runned in IOS and android devices. I'm getting out of memory only in the android devices.

Here is my logCat output, but I think that it wouldn't show nothing new.

```
01-12 15:35:25.271: D/dalvikvm(13948): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 297K, 6% free 9580K/10160K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
01-12 15:35:25.321: D/dalvikvm(13948): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 297K, 6% free 9580K/10160K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
01-12 15:35:25.371: D/dalvikvm(13948): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 297K, 6% free 9580K/10160K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
01-12 15:35:25.421: D/dalvikvm(13948): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 297K, 6% free 9580K/10160K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
01-12 15:35:25.472: D/dalvikvm(13948): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 297K, 6% free 9580K/10160K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
01-12 15:35:25.522: D/dalvikvm(13948): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 297K, 6% free 9580K/10160K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
01-12 15:35:25.572: D/dalvikvm(13948): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 298K, 6% free 9581K/10160K, paused 15ms, total 16ms
...
```

**EDIT** 
I changed the code to the suggestions make in comments, but it didn't work. Also I change the while(true) by an update(dt) that is the real method that run this piece of code.

**EDIT 2**
Here is the sprintf version, as I say, this also consumes a lot of memory. Also I changed the type of actualScore to int. On the header file I declared score as `char score[16];`

```
update(dt){
    actualScore += combo;
    sprintf(score, "%d", actualScore);
    scoreLabel->setString(score);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to only change the score and do the calculations if the score is different than the one in the previous frame?
So, only update when the score changes. That might free up some memory

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder` declared outside the loop and as Dries says, only change it when you need to.

Comment: Its off topic but `std::to_string` comes to mind. Also, add `scoreString.clear();`

Comment: You are sure 'scoreLabel->setString' is no issue !
?

Comment: This infinit loop, is an update(deltatime) method, that is called every frame. So in every frame the score change.

Comment: @gassim I tried `scoreString.clear()` but it haven't solve my problem. I will try to use `to_string` but I think that does the same that I am doing. This problem with the memory also happen using `sprintf()`.

Comment: @dieter I am sure the problem is no setString, if I comment << it works fine, and if I comment setString nothing change.

Comment: @GabrielEsteban: If the problem with the memory also happens with `sprintf`, that's pretty conclusive evidence that either (A) you did it in a wierd way, or (B) the problem is `scoreLabel->setString`.  Can we see the sprintf version and `scoreLabel->setString` code?

Comment: @MooingDuck `scoreLabel->setString` is a method that provides the cocos2dx game engine to set the text of a Label(like EditText.setText() on java).

Comment: @GabrielEsteban: That doesn't actually affect things.  (A) you did sprintf in a wierd way, or (B) the problem is `scoreLabel->SetString` and there's nothing you can do to make it better.

Comment: @MooingDuck I uploaded my sprintf version. And doesn't work well. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @GabrielEsteban: Your `sprintf` code that you posted does no allocations whatsoever.  Ergo, we can conclude that the allocations are either (A) in `scoreLabel->SetString`, or (B) in unrelated code.  Considering your app is using ~9581499 bytes and surprising the GC, and it's hard to imagine `SetString` using that much, and I'd posit that the memory is being used elsewhere.  As a test, run it with the whole loop body commented out.  That should confirm.

Comment: @MooingDuck I think that the << or sprintf is the the straw that broke the camel's back, the problem is in the other code that is inside the loop. I will read it again and think what's causing this memory allocation, I think that i will close the question, as there is no way to solve with the actual code.

Comment: @MooingDuck Finally I discovered that the problem was from using one type af label that is very slow and waste a lot of memory. Now I'm using CCLabelBMFont that is faster. Thanks for all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label that I was using was CCLabelTTF that is slow and waste a lot of memory.
I started using CCLabelBMFont that is faster, that solved the memory allocation.

I found that at http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Text_Labels where it explains the use of the different types of labels that cocos2d-x have.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve used stringstream  << once in my code, and it caused un-usual memory leak and crashing app in android app. Avoid it and use **sprintf** instead.

Comment: With sprintf it doesn't work well. I uploaded my code using sprintf. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean id didn’t work? Have you got any error message?

Comment: And one note, if you're using older versions of C++ compiler, you may need to add #include <stdio.h>

Comment: Finally I discovered that the problem was from using one type af label that is very slow and waste a lot of memory. Now I'm using CCLabelBMFont that is faster. Thanks for all!